# Are questions about GenAI API prices on-topic or off-topic on this site?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Here is an example of a question about GenAI API prices:

> Question about Azure OpenAI pricing: Assume I ran 2 queries on GPT-4 (8k-token context). Each query consisted of 8 prompt tokens. Each query returned 2 completion tokens. Let's assume I don't use any special price discount. Does that cost 0.03 + 0.06 USD, or (0.03 + 0.06) * 2 USD? I looked at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/ and  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/openai-service/  but couldn't find the information.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, questions about prices of anything should be off-topic. It depends on many factors and the price can be changed by the owner of the product at any time. Price can, most of the time, be varied depending on some attributes of the purchaser. For example, location, nationality, or even connection with the seller.

This makes it unsuitable for our site. A question asking about prices of a GenAI API will maybe have a correct answer for one person for a single period of time, and another correct answer for another person in another period of time.

I suggest the asker who really want to know the price to just ask the product owner directly. That would be the best approach.